# StreamSocketListener Recive Multiple Messages

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp, listener

This is my code, can you help me to change the code so that I can recive multiple messages? At the moment I can just recive one question then the client must reconnect.

I hope you can help me.

```
public string PortNumber = "1337";

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    StartServer();
}

private async void StartServer()
{
    try
    {
        var streamSocketListener = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener();

        // The ConnectionReceived event is raised when connections are received.
        streamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived += this.StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

        // Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port. You can specify any port that's not currently in use.
        await streamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(this.PortNumber);

        this.serverListBox.Items.Add("server is listening...");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketErrorStatus webErrorStatus = Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
        this.serverListBox.Items.Add(webErrorStatus.ToString() != "Unknown" ? webErrorStatus.ToString() : ex.Message);
    }
}

private async void StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    string request;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
    {
        request = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
    }

    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => this.TB1.Text=(string.Format("server received the request: \"{0}\"", request)));

    // Echo the request back as the response.
    using (Stream outputStream = args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite())
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
        {
            await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(request);
            await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always listen the upcoming message in the [StreamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener.connectionreceived), this event will only trigger when a connection was received on the [StreamSocketListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener) object. If you want to always receive the sent data, you should always read it in the [StreamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener.connectionreceived).

Here is the sample code in the official [StreamSocket](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket/cs)：

In the [Scenario1_Start.xaml.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/StreamSocket/cs/Scenario1_Start.xaml.cs), the `OnConnection` is same as your `StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived` method. You can also learn more from the official sample.

```
private async void OnConnection(
    StreamSocketListener sender, 
    StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    DataReader reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Read first 4 bytes (length of the subsequent string).
            uint sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
            if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
            {
                // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
                return;
            }

            // Read the string.
            uint stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
            uint actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(stringLength);
            if (stringLength != actualStringLength)
            {
                // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
                return;
            }

            // Display the string on the screen. The event is invoked on a non-UI thread, so we need to marshal
            // the text back to the UI thread.
            NotifyUserFromAsyncThread(
                String.Format("Received data: \"{0}\"", reader.ReadString(actualStringLength)), 
                NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
        if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
        {
            throw;
        }

        NotifyUserFromAsyncThread(
            "Read stream failed with error: " + exception.Message, 
            NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```